# Linked Access Query (relying on Oracle ODBC connection) to Excel not Returning All Records

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc, ms-access-2010, excel-external-data

I am trying to link the output from an Access Query to an Excel document and I've run into a issue where all the records are not returned.  When this query is run from Access, the format and number of records is correct according to the SQL.  However, when I manage to link it to Excel, some of the fields are in positions not consistent with the query in Access and a few records are left off altogether.

The query relies on Oracle ODBC connections for which a password is required.  I used the Import Wizard in Excel to save the password so that it can refresh properly without user input again.  Is this the reason for the fewer number of rows returned?

At first I thought this issue might be happening because some fields do not have any data supplied.  To work around this, I changed the query in Access to sort by a field that has some sort of data by descending, but this did not seem to work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Does your SQL table have a defined Primary Key?

Comment: It does not. Could that be the problem?

Comment: It could, depending on your query. For example, if you're filtering on certain values or grouping in any way. Can you make a copy of the table and add a primary key to see if it helps?